# Center group of radio buttons with labels

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have a bunch of radio buttons with labels of variable length. I was wondering how I can horizontally center them so that the labels are at the center of the page, but appear 'left aligned'.

Desired outcome:

[image]

Current HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" name="option" id="option#" value="radiobutton" />
<label class="databaseoption" for="option#">Text of variable length</label><br />
```

Comment: I’d say, put them into a container element with `display:inline`, and center that by giving the parent `text-align:center`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: table` is good for this: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/vKkAq

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

div {display: table; margin: 0 auto; padding: 30px; background: #e7e7e7; border: 1px solid black;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="option#" value="radiobutton" />
    <label class="databaseoption" for="option#">Text</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="option#" value="radiobutton" />
    <label class="databaseoption" for="option#">Text of variable</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="option#" value="radiobutton" />
    <label class="databaseoption" for="option#">Text of variable length</label>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by using a `<div>` which is center-aligned, and then use a `<span>` styled as an inline-block,

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <span style="text-align: left; display: inline-block; border: 1px solid grey; padding: 0.5em;">
        <input type="radio" name="option" id="option#" value="radiobutton" />
        <label class="databaseoption" for="option#">Text of variable length</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="option" id="option#" value="radiobutton" />
        <label class="databaseoption" for="option#">Text of variable length variable lenght</label><br />
        <input type="radio" name="option" id="option#" value="radiobutton" />
        <label class="databaseoption" for="option#">Text of variable length variable</label><br />
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a borderless table and have the actual radio buttons separate from their labels.

or if you don't want to use a table, use divs with relative positioning and perhaps attribute float set to left.